# Saving form when there is autopostback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I'm very new to MVC3.In my view page I've a dropdown list and some fields data in the following way.

View:-

```
 //dropdownlist data
 @Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(categoriesList, selectedCategory), "Select One", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })


  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)


  <input type="submit" name="Create" value="Create" />
```

Here both the submit button and dropdown control submitting the form I'm wondering how the controller can identify the call is happened via submit button but not from the dropdownlist. your help is really appreciate.

Comment: Please clarify what do you exactly want to do.

Comment: I don't see that your sample is in a form?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `AutoPostback` concept in `ASP.NET MVC`. Autopostback is a feature of `WebForms`.

ASP.NET MVC uses normal form posting.  so your controller action will get the values when the form is posted by clicking on the submit button.

you can always write some javascript code to listen to the `change` event of the dropdown and so a form submit. So in your case, It is the `onchange` event calling the `form.submit` method

Comment: I got the solution. Just name the buttons and pass the button name as String to the controller method and verify with the vale by doin the following.

Comment: @Trinadh : post it as an answer then so others can also know